# column.getHeaderGroupProps is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-table

I am writing the [react-table getting started](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start#final-result) with typescript, however I am getting an error on the data I am passing into my table function:

```
column.getHeaderGroupProps is not a function
TypeError: column.getHeaderGroupProps is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:276:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:271:47
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SortingTable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:269:38)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34299:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent
```

Being new to react/typescript pointers much appreciated on my SortingTable.tsx below, if I comment out the `Table` function the page loads, so I am doing something wrong with my types just not sure what.

```
export const SortingTable=():any=>{
    const columns:any = useMemo(()=> GROUP_COLUMNS, [])
    const data:any = useMemo(()=> MOCK_DATA, [MOCK_DATA] )

    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    },
        useSortBy
    )


    const {getTableProps,getTableBodyProps,headerGroups,rows,prepareRow,footerGroups} = tableInstance

    return(
        <React.Fragment key={data.id} >
            <Card sx={{border:'1px solid black',width:'100%'}}>

                <CardContent >
                    <TableContainer  sx={{ maxHeight: 600 }} component={Paper} className='tableComp'>
                        <Table stickyHeader {...getTableProps} >
                            <TableHead>
                                {
                                    headerGroups.map((headerGroup:any)=>(

                                            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps} >
                                                {
                                                    headerGroup.headers.map((column:any)=>(
                                                        <TableCell key={column.render('id')} sx={{bgcolor:'black',color:'white'}}
                                                                   {...column.getHeaderGroupProps()}
                                                        >
                                                            {
                                                                column.render('Header')
                                                            }

                                                        </TableCell>
                                                    ))
                                                }
                                            </TableRow>
                                        )
                                    )
                                }

                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody {...getTableBodyProps}>
                                {
                                    rows.map((row:any)=>{
                                        prepareRow(row)
                                        return(
                                            <TableRow {...row.getRowProps}>
                                                {
                                                    row.cells.map((cell:any,index:number)=>{
                                  
                                                        return(
                                                            <TableCell key={cell.value}                           {...cell.getCellProps}>
                                                                {cell.render('Cell')}
                                                            </TableCell>
                                                        )
                                                    })
                                                }
                                            </TableRow>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </TableBody>


                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>

                </CardContent>

            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: if you want to pass `column.getHeaderGroupProps` as props, you should not call it: `...column.getHeaderGroupProps` (without `()`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pass props the wrong way

```
<TableCell key={column.render('id')} sx={{bgcolor:'black',color:'white}}
{...column.getHeaderGroupProps()}
>
```

Instead, try passing the props as a single object

```
const sx={{bgcolor:'black',color:'white'}};
const key = column.render('id');
<TableCell {...column.getHeaderGroupProps(), key:key, sx:sx}/>
```